# STM32 VCP on Linux is super slow

Tags: linux, serial-port, stm32, pyserial, stm32f4discovery

I use the USB OTG device on my STM32F407-Discovery to send and receive data with pyserial - using the USB CDC interface provided by STM32CubeMX. On Windows (with ST VCP drivers), I get a very decent speed that suit my needs. Running a python script that sends/receive the same string (a sort of 'echo' from/to the STM32), it takes about 3 seconds to complete the test, with 10000 packets.

On Linux, using /dev/ttyACM0, it takes 30 seconds. That means the speed on Linux is about 10x less. Changing the baudrate with stty doesn't seem to have any effect. This was tested on Ubuntu 17.10 with VirtualBox.

I wonder, how can I make the serial port on Linux as fast as on Windows?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean that You have tested it on Linux which is a guest OS?

Comment: Yes, basically Linux was running on VirtualBox, which runs on Windows.

Comment: So I prefer firstly to check VB related issues as this could cause the problem. To be sure You could check execution time of the tests on a machine where Linux is a host OS.

Comment: Sadly I have not yet tested with Linux as a host OS, I only used it as a guest OS. If you think it could be the problem, I will indeed have to check

Comment: Well, for some reason it works very good on native Linux. Perhaps I asked too quick the question. Still, I wonder why the cause is VirtuaBox, but it definitely was that.

Comment: Look up VB forums. There are a lot of topics about similar problems.